# VBA Autofiler Dynamic Array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dynamic, autofilter

How do i filter a dynamic Array, I've been looking around, but i can only find examples of autofilter of arrays. What I have is a dynamic array that changes the contents based on checkboxes.
It would then autofilter the dynamic array, but i cannot seem to get the autofilter to work with the dynamic array.
With ActiveSheet

```
With ActiveSheet
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    .UsedRange.AutoFilter
    .UsedRange.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=userid
    .UsedRange.AutoFilter field:=7, Criterial:=Array_filter
End With
```

The above filers two columns. i can get the first one working, but not the array one.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. But you need to use parameter called `Criteria1`:

```
.UsedRange.AutoFilter field:=7, Criteria1:= ... '<< with 1 (one) at the end
```

instead of `l` (el letter) which you have now.

**Additional information after some comment below the answer**.

To get all elements from array you need to add additional parameter in discussed line of code:

```
.UsedRange.AutoFilter field:=7, Criteria1:=Array_filter, Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

**`Operator:=xlFilterValues`** is a key to solution.

Comment: Well damn, that is a stupid mistake, i spent hours trying to figure what went wrong. As i previously compied the first autofilter from a macro, I did not have the problem. Another thing, i can now filter the dynamic array, but it only filters the first item and not the rest. Any ideas?

Comment: could be a problem with range references. Try if `.UsedRagne.Select` cover the area you expect to be filtered. Second, you apply 2 filters for column 1 and 7 together- should there be more then one results?

Comment: and you should also know [how to accept answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) for this and other questions if apply.

Comment: yeah, but since it only solves one part of my answer and not fully, i was going to accept it as an answer after i had properly understood how does it work. And i did not want to open another similar question. Also, when i was refering to the first item, i meant the first item in the array. As the array can change in size and stored item. But only the first item is being used as the filter criterial, not all the items. Thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: Thanks man, that saved it all, i used to include the operator, but when i couldn't get it to work because of the criterial, i thought that XLfiltervalues was the cause of it. Thanks for the help!!